# PHP 8.2 xmlrpc unable to initialize module

Tags: php, xml-rpc, php-extension

I'm currently upgrading my PHP version from 8.0 to 8.2.13. The website is up and running but I keep getting the PHP warning of `Warning: PHP Startup: xmlrpc: Unable to initialize module`.

I've checked the logs and it's due tot he module being complied like:

- Module compiled with module API=20210902
- PHP    compiled with module API=20220829

On the PECL download page I could only find versions for php 8.1 and less.
[Link to PECL download page](https://pecl.php.net/package/xmlrpc/1.0.0RC3/windows)

How could I possibly recompile this module for 8.2 on Windows?

Comment: Since the XML-RPC extension is not maintained, better use a pure PHP implementation like this polyfill: https://github.com/gggeek/polyfill-xmlrpc .

Comment: Once you have the correct PHP source code build system setup, it is easy to compile PHP extensions. However, that does not mean the extension will work due to language and library changes. My repo on PHP SSH2 includes documentation on how to setup everything: https://github.com/jhanley-com/php-ssh2-windows

Comment: Tip: I would first upgrade from PHP 8.0 to PHP 8.1. Fix any warnings and errors in your project first. Then review if you want to make the jump to PHP 8.2. Since 8.3 has already been released, why develop for 8.2?

Comment: I ended up deleting the package which depended on XMLRPC. I tried to build the PHP extensions on Windows but I personally found it difficult due to versions etc. I was following this guide if it helps anyone else - https://medium.com/@erinus/how-to-build-php-on-windows-a7ad0a87862a